# How to use camera in app using Cordova (iOS & Android), similar to snapchat

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

I'm using Meteor and Cordova right now for the development of an Android/iOS app. I've been reading the docs on the Cordova camera API and playing around with it, but so far all I've been able to do is hit a button that takes me to an external camera app, instead of just having the camera already opened in the app (Like Snapchat).

Not sure if the Cordova camera plugin is even capable of this, since it seems like all it does is fire up the native camera app when triggered, but hopefully you guys tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the camera by default like snapchat does is possible, but you should do some tricks to do that.

Now If you want to have it native to *android/ios* yo should write a custom plugin for it.

[Writing a Custom Camera Plugin for PhoneGap](http://codrspace.com/vote539/writing-a-custom-camera-plugin-for-phonegap/)

Also read [Developing custom plugins](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/plugins/developing-custom-plugins/).

So i think you can edit the [mdg:camera package](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:camera) in order to work like you want.